# How to mount a filesystem.git directory during init?

Tags: linux, git, filesystems, mount, unpack

I have a bootable ISO file containing a `filesystem.git` which in turn contains this structure:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 2048 Mär  1 17:10 branches/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  115 Mär  1 17:10 config
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   73 Mär  1 17:10 description
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   23 Mär  1 17:10 HEAD
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 2048 Mär  1 17:10 hooks/
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 2048 Mär  1 17:10 info/
dr-xr-xr-x 4 root root 2048 Mär  1 17:10 objects/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   85 Mär  1 17:10 packed-refs
dr-xr-xr-x 4 root root 2048 Mär  1 17:10 refs/
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   82 Mär  1 17:10 shallow
```

There seems to be a packed Debian filesystem within the objects tree and the `initramfs` image seems to have a procedure to unpack and mount the `filesystem.git` as the root filesystem, but I don't know how.

Can anyone explain, how this works?

Comment: This is a git (version control system) repository, so it seems to be highly unlikely to me that the `initramfs` mounts something from inside the `filesystem.git/objects` tree. From where do you have this disk image? Is there a way to take a look at it? What makes you believe that it's mounting something from inside the repository?

Comment: Yes, you can download the latest ISO [here](http://build.webconverger.org/). I want to understand how it works internally. I have no idea how the filesystem.git gets mounted during boot process, since it's packed, but it has to. I found something called `git-fs` in the initrd image, maybe thats the tool used to mount it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question for other folks having the same issue, you can mount a *.git directory by using [git-fs](https://github.com/Webconverger/git-fs) in combination with [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) as pointed out by Michael Wild.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently [webconverger](http://webconverger.org) have created their custom [`fuse`](http://fuse.sf.net) file-system: https://github.com/Webconverger/git-fs. Looks to me that this is they way they distribute updates: perform a `git-fetch` and then update the `initramfs` to point their `git-fs` file system at the new object. You'll need to read the [sources](https://github.com/Webconverger) (or simply ask one of the developers...) in order to understand how things work exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a filesystem, it's a [git](http://git-scm.com/) repository, so it won't be mounted as such.

Presumably it is cloned from the install media to the root directory of the system being installed with `git clone` and then the `.git` directory is removed, or else some equivalent operation is performed using lower level git commands to clone it without bothering to create the local copy of the repository in the `.git` directory.